# Undefined method with alias_method_chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alias-method-chain

My model has attribute html. When I try to use alias_method_chain with setter html=, I get the error `` undefined method `name=' for class `Banner' ``
But I use alias_method_chain with another attribute.

```
class Banner < ActiveRecord::Base

  def file_with_metadata_handling=(uploaded_file)
    # ...
  end

  def html_with_format_checking=(banner_html)
    # ...
  end

  # works well
  alias_method_chain :file=, :metadata_handling

  # undefined method html=
  alias_method_chain :html=, :format_checking
end
```

Method is defined

```
Banner.new.respond_to? :html=
 => true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model defines attribute's getters & setters dynamically. So alias_method_chain had't found setter for attribute.